# Docker - Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: rootfs

Tags: docker

I am getting error while running the below docker command.

```
docker run -it -v /tmp:/tmp/host registry.docker.com/base/jdk1.8 rm -rf /tmp/host/mesos
```

Error :-

> docker: Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci
>   runtime error: rootfs
>   (\"/tst/app/docker/devicemapper/mnt/140eb7aadfb7e1530a3fc5955f57ae154008be913cf920ba908cf064d5e586cc/rootfs\")
>   does not exist\n".

**Docker version result :-**

```
 docker version

Client:
 Version:      1.12.6
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   1512168
 Built:        Wed Jan 11 09:49:56 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.6
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   1512168
 Built:        Wed Jan 11 09:49:56 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

**Docker Info Result :-**

```
docker info

Containers: 90
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 90
Images: 5
Server Version: 1.12.6
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-249:1-1838266-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: ext4
 Data file: /dev/loop2
 Metadata file: /dev/loop3
 Data Space Used: 4.219 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 43.82 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 8.79 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.139 GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /tst/app/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
 Metadata loop file: /tst/app/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.117-RHEL6 (2016-12-13)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options:
Kernel Version: 4.1.12-103.10.1.el6uek.x86_64
Operating System: Oracle Linux Server 6.9
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 15.55 GiB
Name: host.com
ID: GL42:TV5D:F5NA:3RIU:JW3A:W62C:O4RF:DBIV:WBVZ:U2Q4:FGC7:XX3Q
Docker Root Dir: /tst/app/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

Comment: If you can,  as first step I suggest to upgrade your docker version.

Comment: It may not be the option for now. Anyway, What version you would suggest? What are other options?

Comment: Latest version. What is your server o.s.? Are you using Vagrant to startup the vm hosting docker server?

Comment: Nope, We dont use vagrant and the server O.S is Oracle Enterprise Linux - 4.1.12-103.10.1.el6uek.x86_64

Comment: Quite old the O.S too. Did you looked at https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25382 or https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22684 ? May be you find something useful. Some people downgraded version.

Comment: This was working fine with even oder version of docker. We just tried to upgrade and getting this error. I doubt if there is any permission related issue.